# keycloakprofile id is undefined

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

I need help! I am using

```
"keycloak-angular": "^8.0.1",
"keycloak-js": "^11.0.2",
```

When I do

```
  async ngOnInit() {
   if (await this.keycloakService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.userDetails = await this.keycloakService.loadUserProfile();
      console.log("user id ---> "+this.userDetails.id);
    }
  }
```

I get the following output

```
user id --->  undefined
```

However, When I do

```
this.userDetails.email
```

I get the email id of the user.

The back end spring security application does get the user id/principal.

Please help me with a way to get the user id please?

Answer (score 1):

I got the user id from the following

```
this.keycloakService.getKeycloakInstance().subject
```